# "Zend_Json_Exception Decoding Failed: syntax error" on module:enabled

Tags: magento2, error, zend-framework, bin-magento

When I try to enable my module with `bin/magento module:enabled` I am getting an error in console:

> Zend_Json_Exception Decoding Failed: Syntax error

How can I fix this? When I enabled the same module in local server everything worked fine.

Comment: add you module composer.json file code.

Comment: it's too late, I tried enable with --force and now have bigger problems(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that one of custom modules used in your application has incorrect syntax in `composer.json`.

For detect incorrect `composer.json` try debug `Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo::load or put var_dump($key);` before `$packageData = \Zend_Json::decode($jsonData[$key]);` in `/vendor/mag‌​ento/framework/Modul‌​e/PackageInfo.php` and run uninstall again.

Reference [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154228/16416).