# Magento Upgrade to 2.1.3 Module Disable Error

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.3

After upgrading to **Magento CE 2.1.3** (from 2.1.2) I am unable to disable a module through CLI. Issuing command

`php bin/magento module:disable Module_Name`

results in error:

```
 [Zend_Json_Exception]
Decoding failed: Syntax error
```

any ideas?

> Exception trace:
>    () at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php:97
>    Zend_Json::decode() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:85
>    Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->load() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:208
>    Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->getRequire() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:132
>    Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->createGraph() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:95
>    Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependencyGraph() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:67
>    Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependenciesWhenDisableModules() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Status.php:107
>    Magento\Framework\Module\Status->checkConstraints() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AbstractModuleManageCommand.php:92
>    Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AbstractModuleManageCommand->execute() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
>    Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/bin/magento:23

Comment: can you add -vvv to command and post stack trace

Comment: @KAndy added above :)

Comment: i think that one of custom modules used in your application has incorrect syntax in composer.json. Try debug `Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo::load` or put `var_dump($key);` before `$packageData = \Zend_Json::decode($jsonData[$key]);` in `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/cfw.mydomain.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php` and run uninstall again

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich appreciate the answer it helped me to figure out the module with invalid composer.json. If you can post this as an answer I'll be able to mark it as answered, cheers :)

Comment: i did it, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that one of custom modules used in your application has incorrect syntax in `composer.json`.

For detect incorrect `composer.json` try debug `Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo::load` or put `var_dump($key);` before `$packageData = \Zend_Json::decode($jsonData[$key]);` in `/vendor/mag‌​ento/framework/Modul‌​e/PackageInfo.php` and run uninstall again